# Payment gateway status check for vending machine

Tags: python, automation, payment, status, gateway

I need help with the code that will help a motor to run the convery belt once a payment is made this setup is required for vending machine

I am using raspberry pi for the code in python with razor pay as the payment gateway. I am looking for a way to notify my raspberry pi code to start the motor once a payment is done through razor pay. I don't have a public ip on raspberry pi so I can't use webhook. Option i can think of is through api but i dont have an idea about how i can use api along with my code to fetch the payment made and run the motor and what parameters should be used for fetching the information and how to define the intervals of checking for a new payment.